# Error on getting device info using DeviceManager

Tags: c#, wia

I'm trying to get device info using DeviceManager class in C# and i get the folowing error:
The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x7170f7fc, on thread 0x1448. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

Here is my code:

```
 // Create a DeviceManager instance
 var deviceManager = new DeviceManager();

 // Loop through the list of devices and add the name to the listbox
 for (int i = 0; i <= deviceManager.DeviceInfos.Count; i++)
 {
    // Add the device only if it's a scanner
    if (deviceManager.DeviceInfos[i].Type != WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType)
    {
       continue;
    }

    // Add the Scanner device to the listbox (the entire DeviceInfos object)
    listBox1.Items.Add(new Scanner(deviceManager.DeviceInfos[i]));
 }
```

It started happening after i found a solution online to change the WIA service logon

Services -> Windows Image Acquisition (WIA) right click -> Properties -> Log On tab -> select local System Account and Allow service to interact with desktop.

I tried it, didnt work, so I turned back to "This account" with Local Service user.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a class provided by the standard libraries. Do you have the full name of that `DeviceManager` class and the assembly/nuget you use?

Comment: The class comes from Interop.WIA

Comment: I can't find this library right now, but I'm assuming it is buggy then. The error you get indicates some serious problem with calls to native methods.